# How to call functions randomly.

Tags: actionscript-3, function

I have several function from 1 to n and I want to call them randomly.

```
function answer1();
function answer2();
function answer3();
function answer4();
```

These functions contain lines of code.

I want to call them randomly.

So the number of the function is generated randomly.
I've tried to call it this way but it did't work:

```
answer(randomNum)();
(answer(randomNum))();
```

Comment: You could try using `if`s. Something like `if (randomNum == 1) { answer1(); } else if (randomNum == 2) { answer2(); } ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the functions in an Array:

```
var functions: Array = [
    answer1,
    answer2,
    answer3,
    answer4
];
```

Then call them like this:

```
functions[randomNum]();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

```
var _functions:Vector.<Function> = new Vector.<Function>;
_functions.push(func1,func2,.....);//add all the functions here

var _rand:int = Math.round(Math.random()*_functions.length);//this gives a random number between min and max value, 0 - min, _functions.length - max
_functions[_rand].call(); //or just _functions[_rand]()
```

Comment: The line where you get the random number has me curious as to why you felt the need to start by adding `0` and then subtracting `0` from `_function.length`.

Comment: @prototypical I just copied the function for rand min-max, and replace the variables - didn't notice that one of the variables is 0 :)

Comment: Typing as int, you really don't need to round. `Math.random()*_functions.length` will work just fine, so rounding is really not doing anything.